# I have a svg image with cursor pointer and the cursor is not a pointer

Tags: html, css, svg

Pretty much the title.

I have a image with a css class which has

`cursor: pointer`

When I hover over the image my cursor does not change.
Chrome dev tools looks like the style is being applied. So I am not sure why this isn't working.

[image: no pointer]

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the negative [`z-index`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) value on `#player-controls img` that makes it appear below the other elements. So the hover is not applied on the element itself but anything above it in the stacking order.

Change the value to positive number or remove it and the `cursor: pointer` will work.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: It just happens :) BTW next time please try to show us a demo(code) instead of a screenshot because the bug can be anywhere. It was a coincidence that the problematic code was seen in the image.